# How to find orientation of image using Fourier transform?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

How can i find orientation using fft? Here is the idea ([reference paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0020768305006207))

```
1. Find the fft2 x(u,v)=fft2(x(x,y))

2. ur=sqrt(u.^2+V.^2),theta=atan2(v,u)  

3. X(ur,theta)=x(ur*cos(theta),ur*sin(theta))  

4. power of dft p(ur,theta)=abs(X(ur,theta).^2)  

5. found the angular DFT by summing the power of annual band between radial frequency ur1 and ur2  
A(theta)=sum(p(ur,theta))
```

My problem is how can I implement the last step? Here is the code that I tried but could not understand the last step. Matlab code:

```
    t=imread('untitled5.png');
    fontSize=12
    [m,n]=size(t);
    img=fftshift(t(:,:,2));
    g=fft2(img);
    c = g .* conj(g) ;
    d=fft2(c);
```

[image for orienatation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96GjA.png)

Answer (score 2):

```
imgOrg=imread('untitled5.png');
imgGray=rgb2gray(imgOrg);
dft=fft2(imgGray);
dftCentered=fftshift(dft);
ur=abs(dftCentered);
theta=angle(dftCentered);
X_new=ur.*(cos(theta)+(1i.*sin(theta)));
P=abs(X_new).^2;
imshow(mat2gray(log(P)));
```

Now you have to create masks. Here is a reference for how mask should be. Read [`Frequency Orientation` Page 70](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=UM_GCfJe88sC&pg=PA70&lpg=PA70&dq=orientation%20for%20dft&source=bl&ots=-goyMkYYH5&sig=RUHRkBrZP8pgdNIsyMOYCYnTgRY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiP9cePuvDMAhVGto8KHTfqA-AQ6AEILzAC#v=onepage&q=orientation%20for%20dft&f=false)

Here is something to start with [Pixels between 2 intersecting lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13245012/pixels-between-2-intersecting-lines)

Create a mask with same dimension as image and multiple it with `P` and sum the matrix. You will get the `A(Theta)` for that direction. If first mask is at `mask(:,:,1)` and if you have 4 masks (`mask(:,:,1),mask(:,:,2),mask(:,:,3),mask(:,:,4)`). Then rest of the code will be.

```
for indexTheta=1:4
    A(indexTheta)=sum(sum(P.*mask(:,:,indexTheta)));
end
```

Now you will have `A` for four directions. Now you are done.

Comment: I want to find the orientation .I mean i know the orientation of those line is 90 degree .I want  to find that value from Fourier power spectrum.

Comment: What you want is a single value for orientation?

Comment: Can you please update your idea in the question in a more detailed manner. If you have any reference for your last step. Include that also.

Comment: I added the reference paper in my q.I would be grateful if you could guide me to implement the idea.

Comment: Thank you.I am trying to follow your idea.

Comment: It is better to avoid the `ur1` and `ur2` in the last equation(`A(theta)`) of your reference paper ,instead sum till the end. If you really want to do that also. Create a circular mask with inner radius ur1 and outer radius ur2 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30592110/circular-mask-in-matlab). Then multiply it with your current mask to get the new mask and use that mask instead.

Comment: Thank you.I am now trying to understand the mask technique.